# Function not found in HTML when using "onclick" with a function and script is tagged

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am making a login page with a firebase database. But, I get an error when pressing the "register" button.

I am using firebase version 9.19.1. I don't know if this will make a difference, but here you go.

This is the error I get:

```py
index.html:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: register is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:34:65)
```

HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login + Firebase Database</title>
         <!-- Cool Google Fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bowlby+One+SC&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Our stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="content_container">
            <div id="form_container">
 
                <div id="form_header_container">
                    <h2 id="form_header"> Login + Firebase Database </h2>
                </div>

                <div id="form_content_container">
                    <div id="form_content_inner_container">
                        <input type="text" id="full_name" placeholder="Full name">
                        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
                        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="New Password">

                        <input type="text" id="favourite_song" placeholder="The Best Song Ever">
                        <input type="text" id="milk_before_cereal" placeholder="Milk Before Cereal? ( Yes | No )">

                        <div id="button_container">
                            <button onclick="login()" id="1">Login</button>
                            <button onclick="register()" id="2">Register</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<script src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS code:

```js
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAOHZgsV3Fk3fpw161NLp_NoqLeUPeCrGM",
  authDomain: "daring-fin-310722.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "daring-fin-310722",
  storageBucket: "daring-fin-310722.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "766339557711",
  appId: "1:766339557711:web:f34a0c4c3f37ee4532bd3a"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  // Initialize variables
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  const database = firebase.database()
  
  // Set up our register function
  function register () {
    // Get all our input fields
    email = document.getElementById('email').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
    full_name = document.getElementById('full_name').value
    favourite_song = document.getElementById('favourite_song').value
    milk_before_cereal = document.getElementById('milk_before_cereal').value
  
    // Validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false) {
      alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!')
      return
      // Don't continue running the code
    }
    if (validate_field(full_name) == false || validate_field(favourite_song) == false || validate_field(milk_before_cereal) == false) {
      alert('One or More Extra Fields is Outta Line!!')
      return
    }
   
    // Move on with Auth
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      // Declare user variable
      var user = auth.currentUser
  
      // Add this user to Firebase Database
      var database_ref = database.ref()
  
      // Create User data
      var user_data = {
        email : email,
        full_name : full_name,
        favourite_song : favourite_song,
        milk_before_cereal : milk_before_cereal,
        last_login : Date.now()
      }
  
      // Push to Firebase Database
      database_ref.child('users/' + user.uid).set(user_data)
  
      // DOne
      alert('User Created!!')
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message
  
      alert(error_message)
    })
  }
  
  // Set up our login function
  function login () {
    // Get all our input fields
    email = document.getElementById('email').value
    password = document.getElementById('password').value
  
    // Validate input fields
    if (validate_email(email) == false || validate_password(password) == false) {
      alert('Email or Password is Outta Line!!')
      return
      // Don't continue running the code
    }
  
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(function() {
      // Declare user variable
      var user = auth.currentUser
  
      // Add this user to Firebase Database
      var database_ref = database.ref()
  
      // Create User data
      var user_data = {
        last_login : Date.now()
      }
  
      // Push to Firebase Database
      database_ref.child('users/' + user.uid).update(user_data)
  
      // DOne
      alert('User Logged In!!')
  
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // Firebase will use this to alert of its errors
      var error_code = error.code
      var error_message = error.message
  
      alert(error_message)
    })
  }
  
  
  
  
  // Validate Functions
  function validate_email(email) {
    expression = /^[^@]+@\w+(\.\w+)+\w$/
    if (expression.test(email) == true) {
      // Email is good
      return true
    } else {
      // Email is not good
      return false
    }
  }
  
  function validate_password(password) {
    // Firebase only accepts lengths greater than 6
    if (password < 6) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
  
  function validate_field(field) {
    if (field == null) {
      return false
    }
  
    if (field.length <= 0) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^9.19.1",
    "type": "module"
  }
}
```

I seriously have no idea what is wrong and don't know how to fix it.
If I made a mistake with my code please tell me. I am relatively new to Javascript, but understand most concepts and can write pretty well with it.

If you need the CSS for some reason, just ask.

And yes, I do have the firebase module installed.

Thank you!

Comment: Are there any errors when the page first loads? If it gets an error loading the firebase module or calling `initializeApp()`, the `register()` function will not be defined.

Comment: @Barmar I get this error: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module``` it says on line 2

Comment: Change your `<script>` to `<script type="module">`

Comment: @Barmar I tried that, it gives me this error: ```Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at index.js:2:18```